# Looking for an optimized way of replacing list patterns in long documents

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

Using tm package, I have a corpus of 10,900 documents (*docs*).

```
docs = Corpus(VectorSource(abstracts$abstract))
```

And I also have a list of terms (*termslist*) and all their synonyms and different spellings. I use it to transform each of synonyms or spellings into one term.

```
Term, Synonyms
term1, synonym1
term1, synonym2
term1, synonym3
term2, synonym1
... etc
```

The way I'm doing it right now is to loop through all documents, and another nester loop through all terms to find and replace.

```
for (s in 1:length(docs)){
  for (i in 1:nrow(termslist)){
    docs[[s]]$content<-gsub(termslist[i,2], termslist[i,1], docs[[s]])
  }
  print(s)
}
```

Currently this takes a second for a document (having around 1000 row in *termslist*), which means 10,900 seconds which is roughly 6 hours!

Is there a more optimized way of doing this within tm package or within R generally?

**UPDATE:**

mathematical.coffee's answer was actually helpful. I had to re-create a table with unique terms as rows and the second column would be the synonyms separated by '|' , then just loop over them. Now it takes significantly less time than before.

**[The messy] code of creating the new table:

```
newtermslist<-list()
authname<-unique(termslist[,1])
newtermslist<- cbind(newtermslist,authname)
syns<-list()
for (i in seq(authname)){
  syns<- rbind(syns,
                   paste0('(', 
                          paste(termslist[which(termslist[,1]==authname[i]),2],collapse='|')
                          , ')')
  )
}
newtermslist<-cbind(newtermslist,syns)
newtermslist<-cbind(unlist(newtermslist[,1]),unlist(newtermslist[,2]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you wish to perform many replacements, this may be the only way to do it (i.e. sequentially, saving the replaced output as the input for the next replacement).

However, you might gain some speed trying (you will have to do some benchmarking to compare):

- use `fixed=T` (since your synonyms are not regexes but literal spellings), `useBytes=T` (**see `?gsub` - if you have multibyte locale this may or may not be a good idea). Or
- compress your termslist - if `blue` has synonyms `cerulean`, `cobalt` and `sky`, then your regex could be `(cerulean|cobalt|sky)` with replacement `blue`, so that all the synonyms for `blue` are replaced in one iteration rather than in 3 separate ones. To do this, you'd preprocess your termslist - e.g. `newtermslist <- ddply(terms, .(term), summarize, regex=paste0('(', paste(synonym, collapse='|'), ')'))` and then do your current loop over this. You will have `fixed=F` (the default, i.e. use regex).
- see also `?tm_map` and `?content_transformer`. I'm not sure if these will speed things up at all, but you could try.

(Re benchmarking - try `library(rbenchmark); benchmark(expression1, expression2, ...)`, or good ol' `system.time` for timing, `Rprof` for profiling)

Comment: Thank you so much, your second tip worked so well. Though it took me so much to put the table correctly. dyplr won't do it for me cuz it doesn't group by or summarise by strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm answering my own question after coming through a parallelized solution that will do things in parallel. It should run the code faster but I haven't compared the two solutions yet.

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
cl<-makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)
system.time({ # this one to print how long it takes after it evaluate the expression
  foreach(s=1:length(docs)) %:% foreach(i=1:nrow(newtermslist)) %dopar% {
    docs[[s]]$content<-gsub(newtermslist[i,2], newtermslist[i,1], docs[[s]]$content)
  }
})
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thanks Fahd. Using your above code I am getting this error: "Error in { : task 1 failed - "replacement has 0 rows, data has 6" ". My length of docs is 6 and nrow of newtermslist is 12. Any idea why i am getting this error. I am new to parallelized solution. Thanks for your help.